# Purge-css seems to remove every bootstrap css in production mode

Tags: css, next.js, react-bootstrap

I am using Purgecss to remove unused Css on my next application. Other third party libraries am using are Bootstrap, react-bootstrap and bootstrap-icons. I followed the instructions from
https://purgecss.com/guides/next.html but it does not work in production mode.
Below are links to  screenshots for both dev mode and production mode.

[dev mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRlo8.png)
and
[production mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCawB.png)

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
"plugins": [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
        "postcss-preset-env",
        {
            "autoprefixer": {
                "flexbox": "no-2009"
            },
            "stage": 3,
            "features": {
                "custom-properties": false
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss',
        {
            content: [
                './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
                './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
                './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*.css"'
            ],
            defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
            safelist: ["html", "body"]
        }
    ],
]
```

}

**next.config.js**

```
 /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

_app.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Head from "next/head";

function MyApp({Component, pageProps}) {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
            </Head>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    );
}

export default MyApp;
```

why is it behaving that way?

Answer (score 3):

You can tell PurgeCss to look at Bootstrap js files for needed classes

As an example, my vite.config.js looks like this:

```
purgecss({
            content: ['resources/**/*.php',
                      'resources/**/*.js',
                      'resources/**/*.vue',
                      'node_modules/bootstrap/js/**/*.js']
        }),
```

As you can see I added all Bootstrap js source files to look for needed classes.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your next.config.js by following

```
  purgeCssPaths: [
    'node_modules/react-bootstrap/**/*.js'
  ],

 // also you can try to make white lists

  purgeCss: {
    whitelist: () => [
      'modal',
      'modal-dialog',
      'modal-xl',
      ...
    ],
    whitelistPatterns: () => [/modal*/, /accordion*/, /card*/],
    whitelistPatternsChildren: () => [/modal*/, /accordion*/, /card*/]
  }
```

If some classes are removed anyway, try following:
This is not entirely correct, but you can make a separate fake component with all the necessary classes that the PurgeCSS removes (modal window, carousel, and so on). You can see the missing classes in the Bootstrap documentation